# Correlation between univariate time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, mathematical-statistics, univariate

I'm wondering about what preprocessing steps are common before taking correlation between univariate time series. I usually normalize the data, but I'm also wondering if the spacing is important as well? In general, what preprocessing steps are standard when analyzing univariate time series? I strongly appreciate any good recommendations on litterature.

Say I want to find the correlation between S&P and Nasdaq in the interval 2008-2018. I normalize the data, is the time interval also significant? Will taking the correlation of the time series in nanoseconds greatly affect the time series in years (10 datapoints), or will this just be noise that evens out? Is removing noise generally a necessary step for getting valid results for correlation?

Comment: How precisely do you normalize your data? And what measure of correlation are you interested in?

Comment: Due to S&P and Nasdaq I normalize the data in three different ways: 1. Logarithmic price, 2. Percentage change and 3. Difference in logarithmic price. I'm not sure if there is a correct way and have used all of them to get a sense of where the correlation should be. I'm not sure what you mean about the second question, but I want to have a correlation that measures a general trend in the data. Will it then be problematic to use very precise data?

Comment: Ah. Thank you. Your transformations are not commonly known as "normalization" (which usually refers to a linear scaling of data to achieve a zero mean and unit standard deviation - or alternatively, a linear scaling to the interval $[0,1]$). I recommend you simply call your transformations "transformations". Regarding my second question, there are multiple correlation coefficients, e.g., the Pearson, the Kendall or the Spearman correlation coefficient. Any answer on the impact of a transformation on the correlation will depend on what specific coefficient you use.

Comment: That makes sense. Regarding the precision of the data: I took the Pearson correlation and received 0.82 for daily data and 0.87 for yearly data on all three transformations. Would you consider the difference to be arbitrary due to noise, or do you think the Pearson correlation for less specific data is more reliable for considering the general trend in the data?